# how can i call datas in a row on html from database

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

i call datas from database but there are not in a row.
how can i do that.

codes;

```
<?php
$test=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siteler");
$sayi=mysql_num_rows($test);
$deneme=mysql_fetch_row($test);


while ($deneme=mysql_fetch_assoc($test)) {
 extract($deneme);
 echo "<div class='container'>
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 back-colour'>
  <p>$site_name </p>
  <p>$site_info </p>
  <p>$site_ref </p> 
  <p>$bet_turu </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>";}
?>
```

thats what happened

https://i.stack.imgur.com/acgYD.jpg

thats what i want

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un1xr.jpg

Comment: One `</div>` is not needed

Comment: i fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
$test=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siteler");
$sayi=mysql_num_rows($test);
$deneme=mysql_fetch_row($test);
?>
<div class='container'>
 <div class='row'>
<?php
while ($deneme=mysql_fetch_assoc($test)) {
    extract($deneme);
    echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 back-colour'>
       <p>$site_name </p>
       <p>$site_info </p>
       <p>$site_ref </p> 
       <p>$bet_turu </p>
       </div>";
}
?>

</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will fix the issue

Comment: No problem, Im glad I could help